# Best way to force android to destroy textures and shaders

Tags: android, opengl-es

I was wondering what is the best way to force android to destroy all textures and shader programs?

I found that calling GLSurfaceView.onPause and then GLSurfaceView.onResume seems to work, but I am not sure if that is correct. The other thing I thought of was to break the game into 2 activities and transfer control back and forth each time a new level needed to be loaded but that seemed to be an ugly approach.

Comment: Why don't you delete allocated resources as expected by standards? Creating a new OpenGL context does this for you but... Why?

Answer (score 2):

I think what you have (pause/resume) should work.

On pre-honeycomb devices, pausing the glsurfaceview destroys the context, which will destroy all of the shaders and resources.

After honeycomb, there is a function called `setPreserveEGLContextOnPause`, which gives you the option to retain the context when the surfaceview is paused. This defaults to *false*, so unless you want to preserve your context it will always be destroyed by a pause event.

Comment: One note: remember that setPreserveEGLContextOnPause does not mean that it will save egl context - check android [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLSurfaceView.html#setPreserveEGLContextOnPause%28boolean%29)